# Slider skipping values: use text box as alternative?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm very new to Shiny.

Consider the following:

**ui.R**:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("The Linear Equation y = 0.1x"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("x",
                  "X-value:",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 100,
                  value = 0,
                  step = 0.1)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("linPlot")
    )
  )
))
```

**server.R**:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  f <- function(x){
    0.1*x
  }


  output$linPlot <- renderPlot({

    point_f <- data.frame(x = input$x, 
                        y = f(input$x))

    ggplot(NULL, aes(x = x)) + 
      stat_function(data = data.frame(x = c(0, 100)), 
                    fun = f, geom = 'line', col = 'blue') +
      geom_point(data = point_f, aes(x = x, y = y),
                 size = 4, col = 'blue') 

  })

  session$onSessionEnded(function() { stopApp() })

})
```

[image]

**The main problem I have with this is that the slider does not allow for EACH 0.1 to be chosen. That is, as a user uses the slider, various values are skipped. I expect that the users of this app will want to choose a particular tenth as a value, and the fact that the slider can't choose an exact tenth is unacceptable for my purposes.**

I assume this isn't a solvable problem using any options for the slider, so I would also like a text box added to the sidebar panel which has the following things:

- The value in the text box can be used as input to do what the slider does (so the value `input$x` should be the same in the slider and in the text input).
- As the slider moves, the text box changes its value to match the value of the slider.
- As the text box value changes, the slider moves to match its value of the text box.
- Values outside of the interval [0, 100] are unacceptable for the text box, and would ideally spit out an error.
- The input of the text box must be numeric, and in the form ab.c, where each of a, b, and c is a single-digit number.

Ideally, if the slider can handle this problem on its own, that would be great, but I haven't found anything that suggests that it can.

I know that this involves `textInput`, but I'm not sure how to go beyond this step.

Comment: You are trying to get 1000 values (100*0.1) into a widget that is less than 1000 pixels wide, which is why it skips values. If you made the slider the full width of the browser it might work, but its still pretty fiddly. Why not just use a NumericInput widget, which provides text entry and up/down buttons?

Comment: @Spacedman `numericInput` in shiny it like `SpinBox` but it also need limit range manualy( use can insernt any numeric value -- more than limit of grow button)

Comment: @Spacedman I want the user to be able to see how the trend changes with the value (hence the slider) and to be able to put in an exact value that they're interested in (hence the text box).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right you need observe and update like :

```
library(shiny)

ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("The Linear Equation y = 0.1x"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("x",
                  "X-value:",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 100,
                  value = 0,
                  step = 0.1),
      numericInput("x_txt","X-value:",min = 0,
                   max = 100,
                   value = 0,
                   step = 0.1)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("linPlot")
    )
  )
))

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

server=shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  f <- function(x){
    0.1*x
  }
  observeEvent(input$x,{
    if(input$x!=input$x_txt){
    updateNumericInput(session,"x_txt",value = input$x)
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$x_txt,{
    if( is.numeric(input$x_txt) & input$x_txt>=0 & input$x_txt<=100){


    if(input$x!=input$x_txt){
    updateNumericInput(session,"x",value = input$x_txt)
    }}else{
      updateNumericInput(session,"x_txt",value = input$x)
    }
  })

  point_x=reactive({

  })


  output$linPlot <- renderPlot({

    point_f <- data.frame(x = input$x, 
                          y = f(input$x))

    ggplot(NULL, aes(x = x)) + 
      stat_function(data = data.frame(x = c(0, 100)), 
                    fun = f, geom = 'line', col = 'blue') +
      geom_point(data = point_f, aes(x = x, y = y),
                 size = 4, col = 'blue') 

  })

  session$onSessionEnded(function() { stopApp() })

})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: This is *basically* what I'm looking for, but it has one problem. Let's say a user clicks the arrows too fast for the text box. (Try clicking one of the arrows and holding it for a while, and then let go.) Then it causes the slider and text box to move erratically.

Comment: It also gives me an error when I close the app: `ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer`

Comment: @Clarinetist I was able to prevent this from happening by wrapping the updateNumericInput in a delay function.

`delay(300, updateNumericInput(session, "x_txt", value = input$x))`